# Read ajax call result outside of its success callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to read a variable outside of a function. I am doing a country detection using an API and looking up a JSON feed. I get the result fine, but I want to be able to use this result outside of the function and I have tried my best, but can't understand how to fix this. My code attempt so far.

```
var country; // defining country outside of function.

jQuery.getJSON('https://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?', function (data) { 

    var country = data.address.country;
    console.log(country) // this returns correct result

}); // end location country check function

console.log(country) // This is reading undefined as is not picking up the new var = country resulted from above function.
```

How do I use the new resulted country variable outside of the function?

Thank You

Comment: Remove the second 'var' (inside the function).

Comment: The important thing to note is that getJSON is a **deferred function** not any other function. It does not run synchronously like your expecting it to.

Comment: @PSL thanks, I could not find that answer today at all. Must of been searching for wrong keywords..Damm -1 for not seeing that, anyway..cheers for help everyone

Answer (score 4):

`getJSON` works in an asynchronous way.

The last `console.log` is called before the callback.

Comment: This is not the root cause of the problem (that's the `var` in the callback function) but this _is_ actually a good point!

Comment: They are different `country`s, so joke's on multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

when you declare `var country` you are shadowing the global `country`. As CD.. pointed out `getJSON` is asynchronous so you will need to check if it has been set before using it

```
var country; // defining country outside of function.

jQuery.getJSON('https://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?', function (data) { 

   country = data.address.country;
   console.log(country) // this returns correct result

}); // end location country check function

console.log(country || "No country set yet, check back soon!");
```

Comment: not the main issue in my opinion but still an issue +1